# How to define the input language

Tags: react-native

Defining the keyboard type in `React-Native` is pretty streigh forward:

```
<Input keyboardType='decimal-pad' />
```

But depending on the language and region of iOS it opens different keyboards. This issue happens both for alphabetic and numeric inputs/keyboards.

I need to open English keyboard in a specific input. for example, `numeric` or `decimal-pad` with dot (instead of comma) as floating point separator for numbers.

Is it possible to define a default language for an input?

Comment: I have the same question. Any one has ideas ?

Comment: Same problem here. Any  suggestion?